# I've created a Cloud Function from Pub/Sub topic, shall I expect retry a delivery of message from pub/sub if function fails?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a function with a simple test code like:

```
    exports.helloPubSub = (event, context) => {
      const message = event.data
         ? Buffer.from(event.data, 'base64').toString()
         : 'Hello, World';
      console.log(context);
      throw new Error("Fail");
    };
```

When I publish a message to Pub/sub the function fails and I expect that it will be called again with the same message after 600 seconds since the pub/sub subscription has Acknowledgement deadline set to 600 Seconds.
But it does not work as expected looks like it acks the message immediately despite the failure in a cloud function.

According to the doc: *Cloud Functions acks the message internally upon successful function execution.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must make sure that you have enabled retries on the function. From the ["Retrying Background Functions" documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/retries#semantics_of_retry) (emphasis mine):

> Cloud Functions guarantees at-least-once execution of a background
> function for each event emitted by an event source. However, **by
> default, if a function invocation terminates with an error, the
> function will not be invoked again, and the event will be dropped**.
> When you enable retries on a background function, Cloud Functions will
> retry a failed function invocation until it completes successfully, or
> the retry window (by default, 7 days) expires.

You can enable retries by providing the `--retry` option when creating the function via the gcloud command-line tool or checking the "Retry on failure" box when creating via the Cloud Console.

When a Cloud Function fails and retry is enabled, it nacks the message, which makes the message a candidate for redelivery. To delay the redelivery of nacked messages, you can set up a [RetryPolicy](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.subscriptions#retrypolicy) on the subscription. To update the subscription to use a retry policy, find the name of the subscription created by Cloud Functions in the Cloud Console Pub/Sub section. Then, for example, you can issue this `gcloud` command to set the minimum retry delay to 1 second and the maximum delay to 60 seconds:

```
gcloud pubsub subscriptions update <subscription name> --min-retry-delay=1s --max-retry-delay=60s
```

Comment: I tried that approach but it will retry the function immediately without delay(Acknowledgement deadline). Unfortunately, this retry option is nothing to do with Pub/Sub it is a general solution.

Comment: Yes, you are correct that the redelivery won't be delayed. I have updated my answer with some more information.

Comment: I have updated the answer with information about how to add a delay for the redeliveries.