# Google Cloud - Pub Sub Push Subscription invoked cloud function retry

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

Pub Sub topic invokes a cloud function endpoint upon receiving a new message.

If any error happens inside the cloud function the function returns an error.

1. Whether the delivery will be retried by the PubSub in case of error?
2. The Cloud function deployed without the retry option. Want to have the retry control on the Pub Sub.

Tried a sample pub sub topic triggered cloud function which always returns the error on execution,

**

```
import (
    "context"
    "errors"
)
func PushBackOffTest(ctx context.Context, m PubSubMessage) error {
    print(string(m.Data))
    return errors.New("always returns error")
}
```

**

But the cloud function is not executed again.It ran only once.

ACK deadline 600 seconds. Max delivery attempts 6 . Configured from the G Cloud console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the event to be redelivered in the event of an error, then you need to enable retry in your Cloud Function by checking the "Retry on failure" box. Otherwise, Cloud Functions will acknowledge the message received from Pub/Sub regardless of the result of processing it. Checking this box is what tells Cloud Functions to use Cloud Pub/Sub's retry mechanism for unacknowledged messages.

Comment: Checking this box is what tells Cloud Functions to use Cloud Pub/Sub's retry mechanism for unacknowledged messages.

Does it mean, if i mentioned max delivery attempts as 6, only for 6 times the function will be retried?

Comment: How are you specifying the max delivery attempts?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/pubsub/subscriptions/create#--max-delivery-attempts

Subscription create/update

Comment: But this cannot be specified upon creation of the Cloud Function associated with a Pub/Sub topic, correct? Are you updating the subscription created by Cloud Functions to set a max number of retries?

Comment: Yes. Once the Subscription created , updating the subscription from the gcloud terminal.

gcloud pubsub subscriptions update gcf-PushBackOffTest-us-central1-backofftest --max-retry-delay=20 --min-retry-delay=15 --max-delivery-attempts
=6 --dead-letter-topic=dead-events-unacknowledged --dead-letter-topic-project=test-project

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62149562/ive-created-a-cloud-function-from-pub-sub-topic-shall-i-expect-retry-a-deliver?rq=1

In this post you mentioned, **There is currently no way to delay that redelivery, though there will be changes to Pub/Sub soon to provide more control over that behavior.**

is it available now ?

Comment: Yes, it is available now. If you are not seeing messages go to your dead letter topic after the appropriate number of redeliveries, it likely means that you didn't not [set up subscribe permission on the subscription and publish permission on the dead letter topic](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/dead-letter-topics#granting_forwarding_permissions).